# Proof details of a $\pi$-$\lambda$ Lemma

Tags: measure-theory

Consider $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $\mathcal{I} \subseteq 2^S$.

**Lemma:** Let $\mathcal{I}$ be a $\pi$-system. Then $d(\mathcal{I}) = \sigma(\mathcal{I})$.

First, the inclusion $\sigma(\mathcal{I}) \subseteq d(\mathcal{I})$ is always true.

In order to prove the other inclusion, suppose that we would know that $d(\mathcal{I})$ is a $\pi$-system as well. Then $d(\mathcal{I})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and so it follows that $d(\mathcal{I}) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{I})$.

Therefore we will prove that indeed $d(\mathcal{I})$ is a $\pi$-system.

Sketch of the proof:

- Step 1: claim that $\mathcal{D}_1 = \{ B \in d(\mathcal{I}): B \cap C \in d(\mathcal{I}), \forall C \in \mathcal{I} \}$ is a Dynkin-system.
- Step 2: claim that $\mathcal{D}_2 = \{ C \in d(\mathcal{I}): B \cap C \in d(\mathcal{I}), \forall B \in d(\mathcal{I}) \}$ is a Dynkin-system.

The key observation is that $\mathcal{I} \subseteq \mathcal{D}_2 \implies d(\mathcal{I}) \subseteq \mathcal{D}_2$. And since $\mathcal{D}_2$ is defined as a subset of $d(\mathcal{I}) \implies d(\mathcal{I}) = \mathcal{D}_2$. Together with the definition of $\mathcal{D}_2$ this implies that $d(\mathcal{I})$ is a $\pi$-system.

However, I have struggles to show that $\mathcal{D}_2$ is a Dynkin-system.

i) Evidently, $S \in \mathcal{D}_2$.

ii) Suppose $C \in \mathcal{D}_2$ then
\begin{align}
&C^C \cap B \\
&= (S \setminus C) \cap B \\
&= (S \cap B ) \setminus (C \cap B).
\end{align}
The last two intersections belong to $d(\mathcal{I})$ by definition of $\mathcal{D}_2$ and so does their difference.

iii) For $C_1, C_2, \ldots  \in \mathcal{D}_2$ such that $C_n \uparrow C := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} C_n$ and $B \in d(\mathcal{I})$ we have $(C_n \cap B) \in d(\mathcal{I})$ and $C_n \cap B \uparrow C \cap B \in d(\mathcal{I})$. So $C \in \mathcal{D}_2$.

Is this the correct approach to prove that $\mathcal{D}_2$ is a Dynkin-system?